# How to set active class on anchor tag with Vue dynamic list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to render a dynamic list for a tabbed nav in Vue Bootstrap with the following code:

```
<b-nav-item v-for="(page, i) in pageTabs" :key="page"
  @click="$emit(`${page}Clicked`); setActive(i);" 
  :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === i }">{{ page | capitalize }}</b-nav-item>
```

This then generates the following HTML for each item:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
```

The issue I am having is that when the html is generated on the page, the active class is on the list item tag and not on the anchor tag.

Is there anyway to make sure the class is added to the anchor tag?

Comment: After further troubleshooting I can see that with b-nav-item the active class is placed on the anchor tag if its written as follows:<b-nav-item active> as opposed to class="active" - Is it possible to render a dynamic list this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `<b-nav-item>` looks something like:

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item"><a target="_self" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
</template>
```

Vue automatically inherits the class attribute to the wrapping element of your component. In your case its the `<li>`. To change this you have to options:

Create a prop like `anchorClass` and put it on your anchor tag:

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item"><a target="_self" href="#" :class="['nav-link', anchorClass]">Home</a></li>
</template>
```

and then you can use it like:

```
<b-nav-item v-for="(page, i) in pageTabs" :key="page"
  @click="$emit(`${page}Clicked`); setActive(i);" 
  :anchorClass="{ 'active': activeIndex === i }">{{ page | capitalize }}</b-nav-item>
```

or you just change the inheritance of the attributes like:

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item"><a target="_self" href="#" v-bind="$attrs">Home</a></li>
</template>
```

But be careful with this as this means all attributes you set on `<b-nav-item>` will land always on the anchor tag and not on the `<li>` anymore!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! While going through this I also discovered I can do it like this :active="{ activeIndex === i }" - is this an appropriate solution or are there any issues with this?

Comment: If you use `active`then inside the the component to toggle the class yes thats also right. This is also more safe as the active class is handled inside the component and not outside of it. So you'll be sure always which class is used.